# Animate sidebar to Fade in and Fade out as your scroll down the page using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have beein trying to achieve the animation of slowly fading in sidebar as you scroll down and fading out slowly as your scroll up with a delay inbetween almost like its responsive to your scroll button. This is my code so far and if anyone could help or point me towards the right direction that would be great. The sidebar functionality I am trying to achieve [Sidebar](https://www.edercarfagnini.com/?fbclid=IwAR1k6jwnAHuNcYZ0u2b_3NceEb6tQ7wJvMMY8qfByDk3G3w-1xJ4Jo-QuC0)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Navbar = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [lastScrollY, setLastScrollY] = useState(0);

  const controlNavbar = () => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      if (window.scrollY < lastScrollY) {
        // if scroll down show the navbar
        setShow(true);
      } else {
        // if scroll up hide the navbar
        setShow(false);
      }

      // remember current page location to use in the next move
      setLastScrollY(window.scrollY);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      window.addEventListener("scroll", controlNavbar);

      // cleanup function
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", controlNavbar);
      };
    }
  }, [lastScrollY]);

  return (
    <div>
      <nav className={`active ${show && "hidden"}`}>
        <div className="invisible md:visible">
          <aside class="w-64" aria-label="Sidebar">
            <div class="overflow-y-auto py-4 px-3 bg-gray-50 border-r-2 border-black dark:bg-white h-screen">
              <ul class="space-y-2">
                <li>
                  <a class="flex items-center py-5 p-2 pl-12 text-xl font-normal text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-red-500 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                    <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Home</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="flex items-center py-2 p-2 pl-12 text-xl font-normal text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-red-500 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                    <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Projects</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </aside>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Is [this](https://codepen.io/gestok/pen/VwddBgx) what you are trying to achieve? You posted just a code without a reproducible example so it's hard for anyone to give you feedback.

Comment: @GeorgeChond My apologies, that's basically what I have achieved. Is is possible to add delay from snapping in and out? Like in here [link](https://www.edercarfagnini.com/?fbclid=IwAR1k6jwnAHuNcYZ0u2b_3NceEb6tQ7wJvMMY8qfByDk3G3w-1xJ4Jo-QuC0)

Comment: Check the answer and the pen. I included tailwind library, I believe that's what you wanted to achieve. Also, if this is what you need, please fork the pen because I'm going to delete it after a day.

Comment: @GeorgeChond thanks man. I spend so much time trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attach a scroll listener on component mount. This scroll listener is going to increment/decrement the value of a state e.g. `scrollY`. Then, instead of applying a class to show/hide, you directly adjust the `left` position of `nav`. Something like this ([Codepen](https://codepen.io/gestok/pen/VwddBgx)):

```css
#app {
  min-height: 2000px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#app > div {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  background: gray;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  transition: left 0.2s linear;
}
```

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const [scrollY, setScrollY] = React.useState(-300);

  const controlNavbar = () => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined" && window.scrollY < 300){ // This should be the same initial value as scrollY
      setScrollY(scrollY + window.scrollY);
    }
  };

  // On component mount, attach a scroll listener
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', controlNavbar);

      // cleanup function
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', controlNavbar);
      };
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="active" style={{left: scrollY}}> // <-- Inline change left property
        <div className="invisible md:visible">
          <aside class="w-64" aria-label="Sidebar">
            <div class="overflow-y-auto py-4 px-3 bg-gray-50 border-r-2 border-black dark:bg-white h-screen">
              <ul class="space-y-2">
                <li>
                  <a class="flex items-center py-5 p-2 pl-12 text-xl font-normal text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-red-500 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                    <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Home</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="flex items-center py-2 p-2 pl-12 text-xl font-normal text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-red-500 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                    <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Projects</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </aside>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};


ReactDOM.render(<Navbar/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```